# sql problem with question probably with having and count

Tags: sql

I have tried to this query: Surnames same jobs in 2 other projects. But the result isn't what I expected.

I have these tables:

```
CREATE TABLE People (
    pid INT PRIMARY KEY,
    surname VARCHAR(127),
);
CREATE TABLE Work (
    idproject INT PRIMARY KEY,
    pid int FOREIGN KEY,
    job VARCHAR(127),
);
```

Comment: Edit the question add some sample data & desired result would helpful.

Comment: GROUP BY, HAVING, COUNT(DISTINCT) etc

Comment: Please elaborate. "Surnames same jobs in 2 other projects" is not a proper sentence.

Answer (score 1):

These query is for 2 same jobs:

```
select p.surname, w.job
from People p
    join Work w on w.pid = p.pid
group by p.surname, w.job 
having count(1) = 2
```

If you want to know more or equal than 2, you must change the last condition to:

```
select p.surname, w.job
from People p
    join Work w on w.pid = p.pid
group by p.surname, w.job 
having count(1) > 1
```

Comment: Remove w.job from the GROUP BY. Do `having count(distinct w.job) > 1` etc

Comment: If the Work table does not contain repeated rows, I consider this query correct

Comment: `group by p.surname, w.job` will return one row per person/project combination. Will never be > 1.

Comment: The queries are correct. In the given database a project is related to one person and one job only. (As strange as this seems.) If we find the same surname and job more than once, these can only be in different projects.

Comment: Thanks @Thorsten Kettner

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
select w.* from work w
where exists (
  select 1 from work where job = w.job and pid = w.pid and idproject <> w.idproject
)
```

gives you all the rows in table `work` that contain 1 `pid` with the same `job` in 2 or more different projects.
You can join the above query to the table `People`:

```
select p.surname, w.job, w.idproject
from people p inner join  (
    select w.* from work w
    where exists (
      select 1 from work where job = w.job and pid = w.pid and idproject <> w.idproject
    )
) w 
on w.pid = p.pid
order by p.surname, w.job, w.idproject
```

Comment: This only finds the same person in two or more projects with the same job, never different persons with the same surname. But well, with "Surnames same jobs in 2 other projects", who knows what the OP is actually after :-)

Comment: Is there a case that the OP means different person with the same surname?!!! I did not get it this way.

Comment: Yes, as mentioned, it is not clear what is being asked. I translated "Surnames same jobs in 2 other projects" to "Find Surnames for which work exist entries with the same job in different projects". But well, maybe it's "Find persons working with the same job in different projects and show their surnames". We can only guess :-)

Comment: By the way: `idproject <> w.idproject` will always be true, as `idproject` is the primary key. (Which makes a project a one-person-only thing in this database.)

Comment: The condition `idproject <> w.idproject` is needed so to reject the unique rows. If there are duplicate rows with different ids then these are to be selected.

Comment: Ah, sorry, you are right of course. You are asking for *another* row for the same `job` and `pid`. Sorry.

Comment: No worries. This is the reason we use the comments.